# How to hide and show Buttons according to the given scenario

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a select list Named  P2_Status  that has three options

1. CREATED
2. APPROVED
3. CANCELLED

I have also three buttons on that page

1. Create
2. Approve
3. Cancel

These are the following conditions to show and hide above listed buttons

**CONDITION-1:** I want when the **CREATED** Status is Selected then all above three buttons to be shown.
No problem

**CONDITION-2:** When the **CANCELLED** Status is selected then only CREATED Button is allowed to show other buttons should be hidden.

**CONDITION-3:** When the **APPROVED** Status is selected then CREATE AND CANCEL button is allowed to show the Approve button should be hidden

I have tried many SERVERSIDE conditions not solved my issue.
I have also tried Dynamic Action on page reload but it works only once but nothing happens.

someone, please help me to solve this issue I shall be very thankful to you

**HAVE A NICE DAY**

Comment: Answer depends on Apex version you use. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a dynamic action on change of item P2_STATUS that has 6 true actions. For each of the possible values in the select list, create a show action to show buttons and a hide action to hide the other buttons (2 actions per option, 3 option that makes 6 actions in total).

For example the cancel button would have 2 actions:

show action:

[image]

hide action:

[image]

I did find it hard to map your conditions to the actual client side conditions so I used this matrix

```
button >   Approve Create Cancel

status
APPROVED           x       x
CREATED    x       x       x
CANCELLED          x
```

One side note. You say "I have tried many SERVERSIDE conditions". A serverside condition is evaluated *on page rendering* and it has no effect once the page is rendered. So in this case, serverside conditions are not an option.